# Based on count value i have to create number of rows,is that possible without java transformation?

Tags: informatica

Hey guys anyone know how to create number of rows based on the count value without using java transformation in informatica 9.6(For flat file).Please help me with that

Comment: we used java transformation to create those 50 rows

Comment: It would help a lot to see your code.

Comment: Actually it was written by seniors,i don't know how they written.Now they want me to do the same without java transformation.I don't know who to ask that's why i needed help from you guys.Sorry leymannx

Comment: Hmm, sorry, can't really start to try to answer w/out more details.  I need some more info re the context, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an auxiliary table with `n` rows for each possible count value between `1` and `N`:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
...
...
N rows with the last value
...
N rows with the last value
```

Join this table to the source data using the `n` count value as the key and you will get `n` copies of each source row.